# Is it a bad practice to include stdlib header file from a header file corresponding to the source file that needs that stdlib header?

Tags: c++

If a file foo.cpp already includes foo.h, and foo.cpp requires some types from (for example, string.h), which is better, to include string.h in foo.cpp, or in foo.h ?

For example, Guideline#9 in [this tutorial](http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/CppHeaderFileGuidelines.pdf) recommends to include it in the cpp, if possible, but I don't understand exactly why.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, askers on this site are expected to do some research first on their own, show us what they found and why it did not suit their needs. A start, for example, could be to tell us is where you got the impression from that the kind of includes you mentioned are "bad". In the current form, expect your question to be closed as "unclear" or "primarily opinion based", since it contains hardly enough information to give you a sensible answer.

Comment: Thanks Doc.They are bad according to something like Guideline#9 in this tutorial: http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/CppHeaderFileGuidelines.pdf

Comment: That’s not what guideline 9 says... it says not to include header files needed by the .cpp file if they are not needed by the .h file.

Comment: @AhmedAdel: #9 says clearly, if `string` is required in A.h (because, for example, A.h contains a class definition with a `string` member), `string` should be included. So maybe you just misunderstood something?

Comment: Thanks for updates. I can see that the last part of #9 states: Do not include header
files that only the .cpp file code needs. E.g. <cmath> or <algorithm> is usually needed only by the function definitions in the .cpp file -
#include it in .cpp file, not in the .h file.
My question is basically: Why to avoid including cmath or so ever in header file, and only include it in cpp file ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding of a recommendation.

Comment: @AhmedAdel: if you include a header like `cmath` or `string` in A.h, you introduce the dependency to `cmath` to any other file which includes `A.h`. If you do this  *though not needed to make A.h compile on its own*, then you increase compile times more than necessary. That can become an issue when the project gets larger over time.

Comment: ... and if your real your question is about including stdlib files which are not strictly required in the header file where it gets included, maybe for saving includes at other places, you should edit your question and explain more clearly what you mean. Currently, it is not clear if you are talking about includes which are mandatory for rule #11 for the Cpp guideline, or other includes as well.

Comment: @DocBrown, Thanks a lot. This is exactly my question. I will rephrase it.

Comment: New question is better. I can’t retract my close vote unless it gets closed though.

Comment: in general, only include a header file in a file (which might be another header file) when the contents of the included header file are needed.  Doing otherwise result in 'over' coupled code and too many recompiles needed when the original header file is updated.

Comment: I see honor your attempt to improve the question, and I tried to improve it a little bit on my own, but it is IMHO still not of the quality the community here would expect for a good one.

Answer (score 3):

You should have your header files decoupled to the greatest extent possible.

In particular, if foo.h is only ever going to be included by foo.c, it is unnecessary, and if it is used by other files, you will be pulling in potentially unneeded include files to them, which can:

1. Increase compilation time (slightly - this is not necessarily a big concern these days)
2. Require recompilation of more files than needed when header files change (which could take a significant amount of time for a large project)

Answer (score 1):

The rule is: Every header file should be capable of being compiled on its own. If you have a file myheader.h, then a source file with a single line `#include "myheader.h"` should compile.

If your header file doesn't compile without including another header file, then include that other header file. However, there are cases where the problem can be fixed just by using a forward declaration like "class otherclass;", if that is a case then it is very much preferable.

So DON'T include header files without a need, and avoid the need if you can.

Why not include other header files that are only used by the source file? Because your header file is supposed to be shared with other files. It is supposed to contain things you want to share. Why would you want to share internal details of your source files, like what headers it needs? You should share as little as possible.

Comment: To be honest, this is a very weak argument. It boils down to “don’t do it because you shouldn’t” without giving any reasons.